# 2 DIVs are overlapping with float:right

Tags: css, html

I am working in HTML and CSS and I find it difficult to rearrange my overlapping elements.

[Live example on the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/br0re0r4/)

CSS:

```
#posts {
    background: blue;
    float: right; 
    width: 75%; 
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#login-container {
    overflow: clear;
    background: white;
    width: 280px;
    height: 330px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content" class="container">
  <div id="posts">
    <div id="login-container">
        <div id="login">
            <h1>Member login</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

These two always overlap to each other when I resize my browsers window.
I wish I can post an image here but it needs 10 reps.

Comment: What do you mean with overlapping? Can you please upload your picture anywhere, so that we can see what the problem is?

Comment: You'll need to provide more sample code, we should be able to reproduce your issue. Maybe create a Fiddle for this?

Comment: do you mean "posts" and "login-container"? This could be because you did not close "posts"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nxyg0xwd/ is it correct behaviour of your problem?

Comment: `overflow: clear;` doens't exist.

Comment: `Overflow` is a CSS property and `clear` is not a valid value for it.

Comment: Please provide the full code, your example differs a lot from the image.

Comment: @Ellis This is not the code for the posted image!? This isn't even a fiddle created by you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here:
http://jsfiddle.net/nxyg0xwd/4/

```
#posts {
  float: left; 
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 288px; 
}
```

You have to left float the content, and create a margin in the size of the login vid.

Comment: thank you for the answer but it affects the design of the login form and theres , just a little overlap..

Comment: You may say us, how the result should be.

Comment: the post(blue one)  must not move and not overlap with the login form.

Comment: I've  updated the answer. Please see if this solution ist correct. If not, please add more infos/screenshots.

Comment: but sir can you take a look in the #post?

Comment: the texts in the post (i dont know how to call this) scattered in the rigth part

Comment: Try it by yourself or open a new question for this.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask, where are you closing the `#posts` div? This might be because `#login-container` is inside `#posts`.